# How to sort Unordered list with array index

Tags: jquery, arrays, sorting, custom-data-attribute

I'm trying to reorder the list with data attributes kindly see the below code.

```
<ul>
<li data-block="block1">Some Text...</li>
<li data-block="block2">Some Text...</li>
<li data-block="block3">Some Text...</li>
<li data-block="block4">Some Text...</li>
</ul>
```

In my jQuery Array I have following values

```
values = array("block2","block1","block4","block3");
```

So I need to sort/reorder the list in the way of array index like below.

```
<ul>
<li data-block="block2">Some Text...</li>
<li data-block="block1">Some Text...</li>
<li data-block="block4">Some Text...</li>
<li data-block="block3">Some Text...</li>
</ul>
```

Kindly help me to get the proper solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use **[`sort()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort)** for sorting the element

```js
var values = ["block2", "block1", "block4", "block3"];

// get all li with data attribute
var $li = $('li[data-block]');
// sort them based on the index
$li.sort(function(a, b) {
  return values.indexOf($(a).data('block')) - values.indexOf($(b).data('block'));
})
// update the order by appending back to it's parent
.appendTo($li.parent());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li data-block="block1">Some Text...1</li>
  <li data-block="block2">Some Text...2</li>
  <li data-block="block3">Some Text...3</li>
  <li data-block="block4">Some Text...4</li>
</ul>
```

---

ES6 arrow method

```js
var values = ["block2", "block1", "block4", "block3"];

var $li = $('li[data-block]');
$li.sort((a, b) => values.indexOf($(a).data('block')) - values.indexOf($(b).data('block')))
  .appendTo($li.parent());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li data-block="block1">Some Text...1</li>
  <li data-block="block2">Some Text...2</li>
  <li data-block="block3">Some Text...3</li>
  <li data-block="block4">Some Text...4</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Sorry for my delayed response it solved my issue. Thank you.

Comment: @AbdullahAhamed : GLAD TO HELP

Answer (score 0):

You can utilize `.html()` , `.map()` , [`Attribute Equals Selector [name="value"]`](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/)

```js
var values = Array("block2","block1","block4","block3");
$("ul").html(values.map(function(val) {return $("[data-block="+val+"]")}))
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<ul>
  <li data-block="block1">Some Text...1</li>
  <li data-block="block2">Some Text...2</li>
  <li data-block="block3">Some Text...3</li>
  <li data-block="block4">Some Text...4</li>
</ul>
```